# Best practises for defining a dict-like class: should it inherit from dict() or have a dict as attribute?

Tags: python, dictionary

I intend to define a class with properties identified here below, and I wonder what is the best approach between making it inherits from `dict` or have a `dict` has attribute?

## Purpose of the class

It is a dict-like class which instance will keep track of files on disk, i.e. it manages a mapping between a key and the handle of a dataset (it is not directly a file - to be complete, it is a `ParquetFile()` instance from `fastparquet` lib).
Naming this class `DataStore()`, my question materializes then into what is best approach between:

```py
# Defining the indexer class 1st
@dataclass
class Indexer:
    country: str
    city: str

    @property
    def to_path(self):
        # Method to derive a path from an Indexer instance
    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, path):
        # Method to derive a new Indexer instance from a path.

# Approach 1: dict as attribute
class DataStore1:
    def __init__(self, path:str, indexer: Indexer):
        # path: path of main directory, containing several parquet datasets
        # indexer: class used generate a key from path of individual parquet dataset.
        self.data = self._keys_datasets_from_path(path, indexer)
        self.basepath = path

    def _keys_datasets_from_path(self, path:str, indexer: Indexer) -> dict()
        # Stuff with scanfile(path) and so on...

# Approach 2: inheriting from dict
class DataStore2(dict):
    def __init__(self, path:str, indexer: Indexer):
        # path: path of main directory, containing several parquet datasets
        # indexer: class used generate a key from path of individual parquet dataset.
        super.__init__(self._keys_datasets_from_path(path, indexer))
        self.basepath = path

    def _keys_datasets_from_path(self, path:str, indexer: Indexer) -> dict()
        # Stuff with scanfile(path) and so on...
```

## Requirements

- Has specific attribute:

  - `basepath`
- Accept a single type of key (in example above: `Indexer`).

  - check type of key when adding or modifying a new value, raise exception if not of specified type.
- Iteration over keys (like standard `dict`)
  `for key in my_store:`

## Synctatic sugar

- When setting value for a key, behavior is different depending the type of value:

  - if value is a `ParquetFile()` instance, then normal dict behavior is used.
    `my_store[my_new_key] = my_parquet_file_obj`
  - if value is a tuple `(dict, DataFrame)`

    - if key is new, the dataframe is data to use to create the `ParquetFile()` instance, and the dict is configuration to be used to write dataset.
      `my_store[my_new_key] = (config_for_writing_new_dataset, data_to_write)`
    - if key is existing, the dataframe is data to append, and the dict is configuration to be used to append data.
      `my_store[my_existing_key] = (config_for_appending, data_to_append)`

So, given these requirements, what would be best approach?
Maybe the question turns into, what approach is the most flexible to reach given requirements and targeted syntactic sugar?
Thanks in advance for any help and advises!

Comment: Do they have any differences for your two approaches? As I know, the second method makes class inheritance to be `object <- dict <- target` instead of `object <- target` of the first one, thus I'd suggest to use the first approaches, no needing to make things to become so complicated. Or you have special needs..

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I am sorry, i don't understand what is 'they' in 'Do they have any differences'? Also I don't understand what is 'target' in the chain you compare? Chain I can see between 1 & 2 are: inheritance: `dict -> DataStore -> obj` / attribute: `DataStore -> obj -> dict obj` but not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Don't do this. You will end up with code that *looks* like normal dict operations but behaves very differently. That is a *field of landmines* for any developer who comes along later (including you 6 months from now). Use a custom class, with appropriately named methods. Or if that's not your bag, store stuff in a regular dict and manipulate it with regular functions that understand the domain logic.

Comment: @pierre_j Sorry to make you feel confused, “they” means your two different approaches, “target” is the things that you want to accomplish (the results that have `dict` properties). The inheritance that I use is to show you the thing that you have made complicated (the defined `class DataStore*` ). Honestly, I rarely see the using of the second method (`class DataStore2`), which is only happened that you want to construct your own data types.

Comment: Thanks @Xiang & @Jared. It seems that you both share the same advise. There is one thing that I see 'interesting with `DataStore2` is that I don't need to re-define a `__contains__`. A thing I find interesting in  `DataStore1` is that I can expose only the methods from `dict` that I chose (but have to 're-implement' them).
Ok, thanks, I will start with `DataStore1` and see where this leads me. :)
I can see that in fastparquet lib, the `ParquetFile` class which shares some of these characteristics (it has a list of handles toward partition files so to say) does not inherit `list` either.

Comment: @pierre_j: Have you considered inheriting from `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, which is intended for making custom `dict`-like things? It's basically the wrapping a `dict` member case, but you only have to define `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`, and the ABC provides all the other `dict` methods for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks @ShadowRanger. I didn't know about `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. It deinitely seem worth of interest. I am having a look! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pierre_j: No problem. Just to be clear, you also need to provide a `__init__` (which is where you can decide where you'll store the internal `dict`). It's not explicitly stated in the docs, but you're responsible for it too.